# Laravel logs user out randomly

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a problem with the login session for my laravel project. Login is using the normal Laravel scaffolding and it seems to be working just fine. Once logged in the user is served a single-page application that talks to the backend through Ajax.

But the user gets logged out after just a few minutes. Which kind of breaks the single-page app, since the user is building stuff in it and then is rendered unable to save because of being logged out.

In Laravel's session.php 'lifetime' is set to 120 minutes. And I'm using Auth middleware to protect the routes now. It seems to be a problem there. When calling a protected  route trough ajax the user gets the message "Unauthorized". And when the page is reloaded the user is logged out.

This is the handle function in the auth middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Really frustrating.

Comment: I think is better for you to use `Auth::check()`, `auth()->check()` or `$request->user() !== null` to check if your user is logged in or not, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
   'lifetime' => 120, // number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires.

        'expire_on_close' => true,
```

in session.php found in config folder

Comment: That's done, as mentioned in my post. (edited it now to be a little more clear on that)